# Android : Getting Proper TextColor and Background Color Value of TextView for Comparision?

Tags: java, android, xml, textview, widget

In my app, I have defined different colors in the colors.xml file.

```
<color name="colorRed">#fa0000</color>
<color name="colorGreen">#17c104</color>
<color name="colorBlue">#0031a3</color>
```

An integer array has been allotted these colors and I can pick one from it using a random function to assign to any textview as textcolor or background color.

```
    colorsArray[0]=R.color.colorRed;
    colorsArray[1]=R.color.colorBlue;
    colorsArray[2]=R.color.colorGreen;


    int displayColor = getRandomInt();  //Range Specified in Function Definition

    gameDisplayText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,colorsArray[displayColor]));
```

Now when I need to check the textcolor and background color of the textview selected by the user and compare it with any color from my colors' array, I'm always getting a false result because the getCurrentTextColor retunrs a signed value.

```
 if(previouslySavedColor==gameDisplayText.getCurrentTextColor())Toast("Colors Matched");
else Toast("Colors Different");
```

How can I obtain correct value of textcolor and textbackground color which are comparable to colors stored in the array?

Comment: Show your getRandomInt() function

Comment: public int getRandomInt(){
        Random r = new Random();
        int Low = 0;
        int High = 9;
        int Result = r.nextInt(High-Low) + Low;
          return Result;
    }

I have a total of 9 color choices. This function is good and has been tested.

Comment: previouslySavedColor . Where and how to you store value in this variable ?

Comment: Thats a supposition variable. I cut out the core logic to keep the question simple. The problem is in previouslySavedColor==TextViewObject.getCurrentTextColor() part because right side of the operator returns a negative signed value.

Comment: It really depends on how `previouslySavedColor` is assigned. When working with colors in Android, it's very easy to mix up which are color id references (like `R.color.colorRed`) and which are resolved color values (like `0xfa0000`), so it's quite possible that this equality test is failing because you're comparing a color id reference to a resolved color value.

Comment: Values flow in this way:

previouslySavedColor = colorsArray[0]
where colorsArray[0] = R.colors.colorRed and in colors.xml
<color name="colorRed">#fa0000</color>

In the comparison, the color value shows up as a long number (2131361812 is what I'm currently getting) and is being compared to -393215